# Missing Windows 11 Taskbar App Group Window Management Options

Tags: windows, windows-11, taskbar

With the transition to Windows 11, the convenient window management options ("Show windows stacked," "Show windows side by side," and "Cascade windows") accessible via right-clicking on app groups in the taskbar have disappeared. I'm seeking alternative methods or third-party solutions to replicate this functionality. Any suggestions or insights are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try
[phazei / Win11AutoHotKeyFixes](https://github.com/phazei/Win11AutoHotKeyFixes?tab=readme-ov-file) :

> This is to resolve deficiencies of Win11 window management, specifically moving active window to next desktop and cascading/tiling windows.

It defines the following hotkeys :

> - Win + Alt + C: Cascade all windows on desktop
> - Win + Alt + H: Tile all windows on desktop horizontally
> - Win + Alt + V: Tile all windows on desktop vertically
> - Add + Shift to any of the above: Will only Cascade/Tile matching executables (eg all chrome windows)